# WPF - Button Or Action from an item in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have done something very bad, because I cannot get it to work at all the way I think I should do it.

I am writing a small test harness which is to be used to help my testing team test the use of another service I have written, but in order to test the service I need a client.

Basically I have a list of tweets that I am displaying to the user, and I want them to be able to click on the tweet to find out the original raw payload that was sent via twitter.

my XAML is as follows:

```
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="ActivitiesList" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2">
                                        <Grid Height="100">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="{Binding Avatar}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                            <Border BorderThickness="0" x:Name="border" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0.5" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=border}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="Tags:" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5" Margin="1,1,1,1" >
                                                            <Border.Background>
                                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFEEEE" Offset="0"/>
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFEBEB" Offset="1"/>
                                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                            </Border.Background>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="3,0,3,0"  />
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                            <Button Content="View Raw Data" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="105" Tag="{Binding}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <!--<local1:Tweet Id="tag:search.twitter.com,2005:823502379551248384 ( 1000 )" Author="jim parslow" Body="This is the content and is going to be very long so that it takes over the page more and more and more" Avatar="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/539113272553648128/sWcgnCan_normal.jpeg" >
                                <local1:Tweet.Tags>
                                    <System:String>Tag 1</System:String>
                                    <System:String>Tag 2</System:String>
                                    <System:String>Tag 3</System:String>
                                </local1:Tweet.Tags>
                            </local1:Tweet>
                            <local1:Tweet Id="tag:search.twitter.com,2005:823502379551248384 ( 1001 )" Author="jim parslow" Body="This is the content balh" Avatar="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/539113272553648128/sWcgnCan_normal.jpeg" />
                            <local1:Tweet Id="tag:search.twitter.com,2005:823502379551248384 ( 1002 )" Author="jim parslow" Body="This is the content blah 2" Avatar="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/539113272553648128/sWcgnCan_normal.jpeg" />-->
                        </ItemsControl>
```

I have added a button in and attached the entire datacontext item into the tag property of the button.

```
<Button Content="View Raw Data" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="105" Tag="{Binding}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
```

Then in the code I grab this out on button click:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var buttonClicked = (Button) sender;
    var tag = buttonClicked.Tag;

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

I have tried using a button with command, but can't get to work.

I have tried to use events from other controls and add mouse clicks on the grid, but again I cannot make this work.

Everything is currently in one xaml file and code file (I know!!)

The tweet class is below:

```
public class Tweet : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public Activity OriginalActivity { get; set; } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And everytime I get a new tweet I add it to the list and set the list:

```
ActivitiesList.ItemsSource = Tweets;
```

Where Tweets is an observable collection

```
private ObservableCollection<Tweet> _tweets = new ObservableCollection<Tweet>(); 
public ObservableCollection<Tweet> Tweets 
{
    get { return _tweets; }
}
```

if anyone could tell me the correct way to do this I would be eternally grateful.

EDIT* As asking for an example of how to do this properly wanted to know what I tried:

```
<Border.InputBindings>
  <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
</Border.InputBindings>
```

I also tried this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
    Path=DataContext.ShowData}" CommandParamater="{Binding}" />
```

But could never get anything to call the property on the tweet

```
public ICommand ShowData
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }
```

**

### Another Edit: Why this no worky?

**

I have this button in the ItemsControl

```
<Button Content="View Raw Data" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.ShowDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

And in the code I have the following:

```
public class Tweet : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public Activity OriginalActivity { get; set; } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    RelayCommand _showData;
    public ICommand ShowDataCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_showData == null)
            {
                _showData = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowData((Tweet)param));
            }
            return _showData;
        }
    }

    public void ShowData(Tweet tweet)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I AM HERE");
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    #endregion // Fields
    #region Constructors
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute; _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors
    #region ICommand Members
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Why does this not work?

I get no errors or messages that are saying I have anything wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a command to the viewmodel (tweet class) and bind the button to the command

Comment: @Emo de Weerd, I tried to do exactly that, but could not make it work, could you possibly write an example based on the basis of my question?

Comment: It would be better for you to post what you have tried with regard adding an ICommand property, and then posting the problem.  Look in the compiler output, runtime Output, and even load up Snoop to inspect at runtime.

Comment: I tried lots of things, with a property for ICommand, with CommandParameters, I tried using events on the grid. nothing I tried worked, so I thought I would ask someone here "what is the right way to do this" and show them what I have that works.

Comment: Indeed, post your attempt so we have something to review and answer.

Comment: added some things I tried

Comment: How do you set the ShowData property and where it is defined? And what exactly do you want to happen when the Button is clicked?

Comment: I simply want to know the best way to achieve a clieck event on an item in my ItemsControl and then call a function that gives the datacontext for the object I am clicking so that I can perform other things. In the example above I am achieving this by hacking the object into the tag property on the button and calling a global event of click. Which is wrong, and I would like to get this right!!

Comment: I basically do not know how to achieve this in the right way. It should be a really simple thing to try and do. On click of the item, run a task that can effect the rest of GUI i.e display some more in depth data about the item that was clicked

Comment: @jimplode The right way is what you already tried: Create a Command in your ViewModel; Bind the Control on which you want to bind the Command to the Command (like you showed us) and pass what you need to process the Command in the CommandParameter. I suggest you to try again to use a Command and look at the output window (if working on VS) to know what's going wrong

Comment: Updated Question: Made this more of a "Why does this no worky?"